# How many continuous function $f(x)$ exist such that $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\big(1-f(x)\big)\mathrm dx = \frac{1}{4}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, contest-math

How many continuous function $f(x)$ exist such that $$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\big(1-f(x)\big)\mathrm dx = \frac{1}{4}\text?$$

I want to find the number of such functions but I don't know how to proceed. It would be of great help if someone can tell me which theorem to apply or provide with any other hint. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Ideally, none. But life is never so simple.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes you are right, that was an error.

Comment: See https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1965480p13609631 on AoPS.

Comment: I don't understand why people simply downvote a question without any reason.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$t(1-t) \leq \frac 1 4$ for all $t$. [ This follows from $(t-\frac 1  2)^{2} \geq 0$].

Hence $\frac 1  4 = \int f(1-f) \leq \int \frac 1  4=\frac 1  4$ which implies that equality holds throughout. In particular we must have $f(x)(1-f(x)=\frac 1  4$ and this give $f(x)=\frac  1 2$ for all $x$.

Comment: This is an amazing solution, nice trick!

Answer (score 12):

*Kavi Rama Murthy's solution was first and I think it is beautiful. I'd like to propose a bit different approach, which requires less insight.*

Obviously the constant function $f(x) = 1/2$ works. Let's find whether this is the only solution. Write
$$\Delta(x) = f(x)-\frac 12.$$

The equality given says that
$$\frac 14 = \int\limits_0^1 \left(\frac 12+\Delta(x) \right)\left(\frac 12-\Delta(x)\right)\, dx = \frac 14 - \int\limits_0^1 \ \Delta(x)^2\, dx.$$
Hence, as $\Delta^2$ is non-negative and continuous, it is $0$ everywhere.

Comment: This is yet another nice mehtod! Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome!